# How to check/uncheck all other checkboxes on spreadsheet and hide/unhide some columns?

Tags: excel, vba

There are 6 checkboxes on the sheet.

**1st part:**

Each checkbox(except the first one) is used to hide/unhide a column.

**2nd part:**

The first checkbox checks/unchecks the other checkboxes and when checked it unhides the columns from A to E and when unchecked it hides them.

To sum up:

```
checkbox-1: check/uncheck other 5 checkboxes and unhide/hide columns A-E
checkbox-2: hide/unhide column A
checkbox-3: hide/unhide column B
checkbox-4: hide/unhide column C
checkbox-5: hide/unhide column D
checkbox-6: hide/unhide column E
```

I tried the below code to hide/unhide the columns when checkboxes 2-6 is clicked. It worked. But how will i do the 2nd part?

```
Sub CheckBox_Click()

    Dim vis As Boolean, ac As String, col As String

    ac = Application.Caller

    With ActiveSheet

        vis = (.Shapes(ac).ControlFormat.Value = 1)

        Select Case ac
            Case "checkbox-2": col = "A"
            Case "checkbox-3": col = "B"
            ...
        End Select

        If col <> "" Then .Columns(col).Hidden = vis

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Connect boxes 2-6 to the CheckTheBoxes macro and box 1 to the InvertTheBoxes macro.

InvertTheBoxes loops through the sheets shapes. Every shape that is NOT "box 1" will be checked/unchecked and follow by the CheckTheBoxes macro. If you have more shapes on your sheet, you need to change the code a bit. But here's the unmodified answer:

```
Option Explicit

'checkbox-1: check/uncheck other 5 checkboxes and unhide/hide columns A-E
'checkbox-2: hide/unhide column A
'checkbox-3: hide/unhide column B
'checkbox-4: hide/unhide column C
'checkbox-5: hide/unhide column D
'checkbox-6: hide/unhide column E

Dim Vis As Boolean, Col$, Shp As Shape

Sub CheckTheBoxes(Optional ByVal AC$)
    ' If a checkbox runs this code, it will use Application.Caller,
    ' since the AC string would be emtpy.
    ' This way, you can run this macro from another macro (InvertTheBoxes), 
    ' provided you return the shape name (which that macro does).
    If AC = "" Then AC = Application.Caller

    With ActiveSheet
        Vis = (.Shapes(AC).ControlFormat.Value = 1)

        Select Case AC
            Case "checkbox-2": Col = "A"
            Case "checkbox-3": Col = "B"
            Case "checkbox-4": Col = "C"
            Case "checkbox-5": Col = "D"
            Case "checkbox-6": Col = "E"
        End Select

        If Col <> "" Then .Columns(Col).Hidden = Vis

    End With
End Sub

Sub InvertTheBoxes()
Dim AC2$
    AC2 = Application.Caller
    With ActiveSheet
        For Each Shp In .Shapes
            If Shp.Name <> AC2 Then
                ' Change the checkbox status (from checked to unchecked and vice versa)
                If Shp.ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then
                    Shp.ControlFormat.Value = -4146 ' Unchecked
                Else
                    Shp.ControlFormat.Value = 1 ' Checked
                End If
                CheckTheBoxes Shp.Name ' Call the hide/show procedure
            End If
        Next Shp
    End With
End Sub
```

If you want to loop through shapes with specific names, try this InvertTheBoxes2 macro instead:

```
Sub InvertTheBoxes2()
Dim AC2$
    AC2 = Application.Caller
    With ActiveSheet
        For Each Shp In .Shapes
            ' Will only loop through shapes starting with "checkbox-"
            If Left(Shp.Name, 9) = "checkbox-" And Shp.Name <> AC2 Then
                ' Change the checkbox status (from checked to unchecked and vice versa)
                If Shp.ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then
                    Shp.ControlFormat.Value = -4146 ' Unchecked
                Else
                    Shp.ControlFormat.Value = 1 ' Checked
                End If
                CheckTheBoxes Shp.Name ' Call the hide/show procedure
            End If
        Next Shp
    End With
End Sub
```

Simply make sure your other checkboxes have different names, i.e. "cbo-1", "cbo-2" etc. Or try naming them even more thoroughly.